# Swift - Switching between ViewControllers doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

---

I have two `ViewControllers`. Pushing from my `ViewController` to 
my `EffectsMenuViewController`works without problems. The code I am using for this is action is the following :

```
 @IBAction func openMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    let effectsViewController : EffectsMenuViewContoller = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("effectsMenu") as! EffectsMenuViewContoller
    presentViewController(effectsViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

My `presented EffectsMenuViewController` contains a `UITableView` with a custom `TableViewCell` which is called `CategoryRow`. The code for this class looks like:

```
class CategoryRow:UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView:UICollectionView!
    weak var delegate:CategoryRowDelegate?
}

extension CategoryRow:UICollectionViewDataSource {  
 /*snipped code */   
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    ImageObjectSingleton.imageName = DataSource.maskArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! String
    ImageObjectSingleton.isEyeColorImage = false
    ImageObjectSingleton.isMaskImage = true
    EffectsMenuViewContoller.callstaticMethod()
} }
```

In my `EffectsMenuController` I have a method called `calledstaticMethod` which is called by `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`:

```
 static func callstaticMethod() {
    let c = EffectsMenuViewContoller()
    c.didselectItemAtIndexPath()
}
```

This method doesn't do more than calling my `didselectItemAtIndexPath` method which should **dismiss** the current ViewController:

```
func didselectItemAtIndexPath() {
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    let viewController : ViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view") as! ViewController
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

As you can see I tried different kind of code statements. But none of them work actually. However when I use `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`inside an `IBAction`-method, it works like I wanted it but I really the way like the code above...

Any ideas?
Best regards,
Nazar Medeiros

Answer (score 0):

When presenting a view controller, the dismissViewController method needs to be called from the *presented view controller*.

In addition, are you sure you want a static instance of a view controller whose scope is in one method?

Comment: Well..my `ViewController` is presented and the method `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` doesn't work anyway. It only works when I use it within an `IBAction method`

Comment: Where is `dismissViewControllerAnimated` called? Your code might not actually be calling that method. It may help to post more code in your answer.

Comment: As I understand it, you have a UICollectionView inside of a custom UITableViewCell. The reason why you cannot dismiss the viewController is because you're not calling `dismissViewController` in the instance of EffectsViewController that you instantiated earlier with `mainStoryboard.instantiate...`. Instead, you are creating another instance of EffectsViewController here: `let c = EffectsMenuController()`. A static function of a class cannot see any of that class's instances. You need a non-static method of Effects than can be called. Try letting EffectsMenuController conform to the delegate